# hard drive storage clicking

Tags: hard-drive, freeze, noise

I just bought dell G5 3 weeks ago and since i started using it, i noticed that the hard drive makes some noise, clicking noise, ever 10/15 sec. I ran some diagnostics and its all okay. I also done some searching and i found that it is okay if the hard drive makes some noise every 5 seconds or when it boots. But a week ago, the laptop started freezing every 10 minutes or longer for a half of a second, i notice some lagging or an unusual sound i am playing any media. 
Is is all okay? do i need to replace the hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

A modern hard drive does not make such noises. I would back it up a replace it immediately

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to tell the difference between normal read/write noise & **clicking** - i.e. the heads banging abnormally against the stops.
One is fine, the other is imminent failure.

Clicking drive == dying drive.

Stop using it.

If you don't have a complete backup, switch it off until you can get another drive to attempt to image it to.

Comment: the hard drive is supposedly new. i just bought 3 weeks ago

Comment: That's no guarantee of anything at all. Mean time to failure is just that - an average time before a drive fails. If MTTF is 5 years, you'll still get one that's dead on arrival & another that lasts 15 years. All the others will tend towards the 5 year figure, on a bell curve.

Comment: Get any data you need from it and return it

Comment: what about the diagnostics?
it shows that the hard drive is okay. also i can't replace it for the company as these diagnostics is okay

Comment: It is possible for diagnostics to be OK and it still makes noise. I still would not use this drive as it may fail at a most inopportune time for you.